# When checkbox is checked in Microsoft Access 2016, insert checkbox value into a field after hitting the add entry button

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

This is what I have so far, and it is only adding a 1 or 0 in the Group_List field.
Braillist is the checkbox value.

```
Private Sub Command86_Click()

If Braillist = True Then
Dim str_sql As String

    str_sql = "INSERT INTO NCECBVI(Group_List)value(" & Braillist & ")"


    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. My checkbox returns 0 or -1. Braillist is name of checkbox? However, the code you show cannot insert data anywhere. Need `CurrentDb.Execute str_sql`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I believe your code has a typo: `value` should instead be `values` for syntactically correct SQL.

Also, as noted by June7, you are not actually executing the SQL statement that you construct, only assigning it to your local variable `str_sql`.

Therefore, I believe the code should be something like:

```
Private Sub Command86_Click()
    If Braillist Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO NCECBVI(Group_List) VALUES(" & Braillist & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

However, this will only ever insert a `-1` (True) value into your `Group_List` field, as a Check Box control can only return a True (`-1`) or False (`0`) value (or null, if triple state is permitted), and the *then* argument of the `if` statement is only evaluated if the Check Box evaluates to True (`-1`).